# How to get media session token from ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

can I get media session token from ExoPlayer for Notification Media Style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code snippet to get media session token from Exo Player instance:

```
class SimpleSessionCallback(val simpleExoPlayer: SimpleExoPlayer) :
        MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        override fun onPlay() {
            simpleExoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
        }

        override fun onPause() {
            simpleExoPlayer.playWhenReady = false
        }

        override fun onSkipToPrevious() {
            simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(0)
        }
    }

    val playBackStateBuilder = PlaybackStateCompat.Builder().setActions(
        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS or
        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_REWIND or
        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY or
        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE or
        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_FAST_FORWARD
    )

    val mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(context, context.packageName)
    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(playBackStateBuilder.build())
    mediaSession.setCallback(SimpleSessionCallback(exoPlayerInstance))
    mediaSession.isActive = true
    // You can use [mediaSession.sessionToken] for Notification Media Style
```

For detailed implementation, refer to uamp android sample on GitHub [here](https://github.com/android/uamp/blob/99e44c1c5106218c62eff552b64bbc12f1883a22/docs/FullGuide.md#the-media-session-and-controller)